# The Python Variables Value displayed by “watch” in vscode debuger are diffrent from those printed by function print()

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

I wrote the following program to test the behavior of Numpy array view：

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(\[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\])

b = a\[2:4\]

# print(type(a.data))

# print(dir(a.data))

print(a.data)
print(hex(id(a.data)))
print()

# print(type(b.data))

# print(dir(b.data))

print(b.data)
print(hex(id(b.data)))
print()

# print(hex(id(a.data)))

# print(hex(id(b.data)))

# print(b.base)

print()
```

But The address of ndarray's buffer displayed by “watch” in vscode debuger is always change，As shown in the following pictures.

[vscode display1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeTk1.png)

[vscode display2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As5pc.png)

[vscode display3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ7Jz.png)

[vscode display4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s196y.png)

[vscode display5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFOSx.png)

It's also different from the function "print()" printed.

[print() printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUxH8.png)

In my opinion，I think the address printed by function print() is right.But I don't konw why this happend.

Who can tell me why.

Comment: because it is just allocated the next memory space at each runtime.

Comment: The `id` of the `data` memory view is not the `address` of the array's databuffer.

Comment: If you did: `x=b.data; print(x); print(hex(id(x)))`, you'd see consistent results between the two prints.  But that tells you nothing about what databuffer `b` is using.  `x` is a `memoryview` object, not the databuffer itself.